Multiple Postfix Instances *without* postmulti
I have been running multiple instances of certain services (php-fpm, mysqld, httpd) and am now trying to do the same with Postfix.
Searching online, I have so far only been able to find descriptions requiring the use of 'postmulti'.
Is it possible to run postfix instances in parallel without the use of postmulti ? I cannot see why this would not be possible, but have not been able to find descriptions online.
Current attempts
I have found the postfix run-time flag -c /path/to/conf/dir/. This allows for postfix to start with a specific configuration directory.
Running a second postfix instance with this command returns a postfix is already running error.
My other thoughts: possibly, only one instance may listen on the standardised port 25 for mail communication. Following this, to have multiple postfix instances in parallel, they must all sit behind this port-25 bound instance.

Why? This smells like the XY problem.

"to have multiple postfix instances in parallel, they must all sit behind this port-25 bound instance" Or they should be listening on different addresses. If you go this route, running things in containers would probably make your life easier.

In addition to that, you must change not only the config directory, but many other *_directory values (e.g. queue_directory, data_directory and so on). See man 5 postconf. However, I don't see the reason for running multiple Postfix on a single system. Even in case it's really reasonable, taking them apart using containers would be easier to implement and manage.

Thankyou for mentioning the re-declaration of other *_directory variables @NikitaKipriyanov. Presumably, I may define these in the main.cf file referenced by the -c flag in calling postfix start. Can you confirm if defining all such *_directory settings uniquely for a postfix instance is sufficient to run two instances ? I would expect there to be the need to also define separate ports and possibly PID files somewhere ?

Postfix-controlled PID files are stored in a directory process_id_directory, so that's covered. I provided a link; just go there and find all _directory and see which ones exist. Notice that to change them all you have to override a few core parameters like queue_directory, many others will be interpolated based on that. Of course, you need to set up different binding endpoints, either bind to different ports or to different IPs or both. I can't precisely confirm; I never did that. Why would I want to do such strange thing?
